# How can I disable "seekto" in mediaSession?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-player, mediasession

Please I need help.

How can I disable seekto in mediaSession? I don't know if I'm getting the name correctly but I'll attach a screenshot with an arrow pointing to it so you can understand better.

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("seekto", null);
```

The code above doesn't hide seekto. I expect it to hide it just like in the screenshot below. This is the final result I'm seeking for.

[image: This is the final result I'm asking for]

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What platforms are you testing on?  Normally if you don't send any position updates, you won't have a seek bar at all.

Comment: Hello Brad. My bad for late reply. I missed your reply and I'm sorry please. I'm currently testing on Codepen here::https://codepen.io/barryovb/pen/MWzxdxQ. I don't know if I actually answered you correctly. Forgive me if I didn't. Thank you for your comment and I'm waiting for your reply/answer. 

Answer (score 2):

While this won't remove it you can remove null and set it to an empty callback function which should render the seekto functionality as useless.

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("seekto", function(details) {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works well. What I actually want is to make it completely and utterly useless. That is, it shouldn't show any information and the bar shouldn't display either. Please see the new attachment I've added to the question. If you could come up with a code that will do this magic, oh my days. I'll be so happy. Once again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm wondering if [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics) could maybe help you? As Brad mentioned if you arent sending position updates the seek bar should be there at all so maybe could edit the CSS

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not the seekbar for the video per se. I'm talking about the seekto area, the video total time on there and the time left as shown in the first screenshot. I'm talking about the seekto area in mediaSession. Thank you once again. Here's the code you shared with me live on Codepen::https://codepen.io/barryovb/pen/MWzxdxQ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you..

```
navigator.mediaSession.setPositionState({
  duration: 0,
  playbackRate: 1,
  position: 0
})
```

This code works fine with an silence.mp3 (inaudible mp3) and of course with an `<audio>` tag.. I don't try it with a playing sound, I just use this workaround to handle the notification bar the way I want.